# What and where is "the log file" for errors in ROS?

Tags: ros

I ran the following and got an error with something that previously ran well (I was just missing the entire world though and not the robot). Something I did in the middle could be the problem.

```
$ roslaunch my_robot world.launch 
RLException: [world.launch] is neither a launch file in package [my_robot] nor is [my_robot] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

However, the main question for now is what is this special **log file**? The error mentions it like there's only one and it is evident where it is. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58698861/how-do-i-deal-with-the-rlexception-error-that-occurred-during-rolaunch) has a similar error but no answer. My question for now though, is where can I find this log file? And what what does **RL** stand for in `RLException`?

Comment: You're having a problem with **r**os**l**aunch, so I would guess RL is short for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr -

> If you are using roslaunch, you can use the roslaunch-logs command to tell you the location of the log directory.

---

From the [ROS wiki](https://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Logging):

> 2. Output
>
> There are four potential places a log message may end up, depending on the verbosity level:
>
> `stdout`
>
> DEBUG and INFO messages arrive on stdout if they are enabled. Note that this may not be sent to the screen depending on the value of the roslaunch/XML/node output parameter.
>
> `stderr`
>
> WARN, ERROR and FATAL messages arrive on stderr if they are enabled.
>
> Node log file
>
> Everything enabled goes into the log file. Your node's log file will be in ~/.ros/log unless you override it with the ROS_HOME or ROS_LOG_DIR environment variables. **If you are using roslaunch, you can use the roslaunch-logs command to tell you the location of the log directory.**
>
> `/rosout` topic
>
> Everything enabled is sent to the /rosout topic. Note that until the node is fully started, messages will not be sent, so you may not see initial messages.
>
> Here is a table summarizing the above:
>
> $$\begin{matrix}
> \text{ }        & \text{Debug} & \text{Info} & \text{Warn} & \text{Error} & \text{Fatal} \\
> \text{stdout}   & \text{X}     & \text{X}    & \text{ }    & \text{ }     & \text{ }     \\
> \text{stderr}   & \text{ }     & \text{ }    & \text{X}    & \text{X}     & \text{X}     \\
> \text{log file} & \text{X}     & \text{X}    & \text{X}    & \text{X}     & \text{X}     \\
> \text{/rosout}  & \text{X}     & \text{X}    & \text{X}    & \text{X}     & \text{X}     \end{matrix}$$
>   Also note that this table is different for rospy.

(emphasis added)

Comment: Just curious as to why rospy is different? Does python have different logging philosophy?

Comment: @heretoinfinity - Probably not that it has a different philosophy, but I would guess Python dumps its own log files to its own location, and/or writes logs with verbosity settings set within the environment.

Comment: Thanks. I found out about unknown logs and `rosclean check` command.